# Program with a separate thread is being killed

Tags: c++

After declaring an object in my main and running its function in a separate thread, my program crashes.

I have read other question on SO but due to my lack of knowledge in multithreading, I cannot understand what is my specific problem.

Here is my class called UART (without header files and only showing the required cpp declaration):

```
void UART::run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            _letter = _serial.read();
            if (_letter == "!")
            {
                _line = _serial.readline();
                _words.clear();
                std::istringstream f(_line);
                std::string s;
                //std::cout << _letter << std::endl;
                while (getline(f,s,'\t'))
                {
                    _words.push_back(s);
                }
                this->fillVars();
            }
        }
    }

    void UART::fillVars()
    {
        if (_words[0] == "s")
        {
            _effort[0] = std::stoi(_words[1]);
            _effort[1] = std::stoi(_words[2]);
        }
        else if (_words[0] == "e")
        {
            this->convertToMeters();
        }

    }

    void UART::convertToMeters()
    {
        std::cout << _position[0];
        _position[0] = std::stod(_words[1]); // / _tick_meters;
        _position[1] = std::stod(_words[2]) / _tick_meters;
    }


    double UART::getPosition(std::string wheel)
    {
        if (wheel == "LEFT") return _position[0];
        else return _position[1];
    }
```

And my main cpp looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "joint_node");
    std::string port("/dev/ttyACM0");

    unsigned long baud = 115200;

    try
    {
        serial::Serial my_serial(port, baud, serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000));
        if(my_serial.isOpen()) ROS_INFO("Serial is %s", "open");

        genius::UART uart(my_serial, 380);
        std::thread uart_run(&genius::UART::run, uart);
        std::cout << uart.getPosition("LEFT") <<std::endl;

    } catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unhandled Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that after creating an object `uart`, I want to run its function `run()` in a separate thread as I want its values to be updated with no interruption on a background. So whenever I access its values like using its function `uart.getPosition("LEFT")` I will get the last up-to date data. I guess I do not need `.join()` this thread as I do not want to wait for it as it never ends.

But for some reason after calling the `uart.getPosition("LEFT")` my program crashes and also function `getPosition()` never gets executed and I always get value of 0.

Comment: Nope, `.join()` is mandatory. *"it never ends"* - this should be fixed as well. One does not want to deal with any "never ending threads". Also this code suffers from the race condition.

Comment: @VTT Yes but I just want the function ```run()``` to run in the background until ```ctrl-c``` is called. Regarding the race condition, why? I do not see that the values could be written by some other thread.

Comment: Then you will need to implement Ctrl-C handler that sets `exit` flag that should be periodically checked in both threads. When it is set main thread should invoke `.join` while background thread should exit. `_position` is read from main thread when it invokes `getPosition` while background thread writes it when it invokes `convertToMeters`

Comment: @VTT Hmm, that makes sense but I just included ```.join``` and the ```run()``` function kept running...

Comment: `join` starts waiting for the thread to exit, but in this case background thread never exits because it contains endless loop.

Comment: @VTT ok thanks, I should read more about std::thread. From my understanding, I cannot do anything after ```.join()``` as it will wait forever.

Comment: That's why I wrote above that you need to have an `exit` flag to be checked in background thread so it can actually exit.

Comment: @VTT Would you mind writing with a bit more details the answer of invoking .join as it answers to my question?